# the value of k increases to 7 than than it is printed?

Tags: jquery

1.i want to concatenate inde & k but it adds both.
2.the value k is given to attribute when it increases to 7.

```
            function iding() {

            $("tr").each(function(index, element) {
                // alert('hello');
                for (var k = 1; k <= 7;k++) {
                    var inde = index - 1;
                    $("td").children("input").attr('id',inde+k);

                }
            });
        }
```

please help in this regard

Comment: what do you mean by point 2... can you check the value of `inde` and `k`... if `index` is 1 then `index` becomes 0 so the attribute will get the value of `k`

Comment: you want something like eg inde1 , inde2 ?

Comment: no actually the innermost loop is for giving id to the text-boxes present in the table.instead of giving id like 11,12,13,14,15,16,17 to row one and 21,22,23 so on to row two it gives 17,17,17,17,17 so on to row one and 27,27,27 to row two

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1: because both of them are numbers... so

```
$("td").children("input").attr('id', '' + inde + k);
```

---

Instead of targeting specific `td`s you are targeting all of them

```
function iding() {
    $("tr").each(function (trIdx, element) {
        var trIndex = '' + (trIdx + 1);
        // alert('hello');
        $(this).find("td > input").attr('id', function (idx) {
            return trIndex + (idx + 1)
        });
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6PdQG/)

Comment: correct to some extent but still it gives output as 111,112,113.....and for second row 211,212,213....
also can you explain function(idx) so what is idx here.

Comment: Thanks... but please explain function(idx) what is idx here and from where it is getting the value

Comment: @user3215849 that was fixed... `var trIndex = '' + (trIdx + 1);`

Comment: @user3215849 [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) has a version that takes a attribute name and a callback function as arguments

Comment: @aks007 it is the index value of the current input value in the `$(this).find("td > input")` set

Comment: $("tr").each(function (trIdx, element) { if we want trIdx to start from 1 what should we do

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate them, use,

```
$("td").children("input").attr('id',inde+""+k);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are numbers, so you have to convert them to strings.

Do:

```
 $("td").children("input").attr('id', (inde + '') + (k + ''));
                                            ^-- implicit typecast to string
```

Or:

```
 $("td").children("input").attr('id', (inde.toString()) + (k.toString()));
                                            ^-- using .toString method = better readability
```